# Confidence interval for non-homogeneous Poisson process where lambda is fourier

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, fourier-transform

I have a non-homogeneous Poison distribution $X = \{ x_1, x_2\, .., x_n\}$ where: $$\lambda(x) = \exp(a_0 + \sum_{z=1}^{Z}(b_z \sin(2 \pi x \frac{z}{Z}) + c_z \cos(2 \pi x \frac{z}{Z})))$$

$$\Lambda=\int_0^T\lambda(x) \partial x$$

$$Pr(X=x) = \frac{\Lambda^{x}e^{-\Lambda}}{x!}$$

The coefficients $a_0$, $b_z$, and $c_z$ were already calculated using some R code and optimization algorithms. I would like to calculate the confidence interval.

Answer (score 0):

A safe method to calculate confidence intervals is to use [**bootstrapping**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)). This consists on running your model over a new sample, obtained from resampling the original one **with repetition** (thus, in a new sample, some observations are repeated).

Say your original estimation (i.e. with all the sample) of $a_{0}$ is $\hat{a}_{0}$. Now, you run your model $N$ times via bootstrapping. From the run $n=i$ you obtain an estimation for $a_{0}$, denoted $\hat{a}_{0,i}$. Then, the bootstrapped standard error is:

$$ \hat{se}_{a_{0}} = \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}(\hat{a}_{0,i}-\hat{a}_{0})^2\right)^{1/2}  $$